# Why do a child class need to implement a parents interface to hide one of that parents methods in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I found this behaviour while working with a third-party library where I needed to hide and change one of it's methods.

I have the following setup:

```
interface IBaseInterface
{
    string MethodToHide();
}

class BaseClass : IBaseInterface
{
    public string MethodToHide()
    {
        return "BaseClass";
    }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    new public string MethodToHide()
    {
        return "ChildClass";
    }
}
```

Why is it that when I run the following:

```
var i = (IBaseInterface) (new ChildClass());
Console.WriteLine(i.MethodToHide());
```

the output is

> BaseClass

, but when changing the ChildClass signature to

```
class ChildClass : BaseClass, IBaseInterface
```

, the output is

> ChildClass

Why do I need to explicitly specify the interface for the BaseClass method to be hidden by the ChildClass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read a bit more about the difference between **overriding** and **hiding**:

Link: [Override versus Hide](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rakeshrajan/archive/2005/05/01/45188.aspx)

In a nutshell:

**Hiding** (using the new) runs the method according to the variable's type.
**Overriding** overrides the method and will only use the child's method.

**Edit**:

When you use an Interface variable:

```
var i = (IBaseInterface) (new ChildClass());
```

The compiler will search for the best match for the methods that are used by the interface.
Because you declared the **BaseClass** to implement the interface, then its methods will be chosen.

If the **ChildClass** doesn't **explicitly** implement the interface, then the compiler can't link the methods to the interface. By its point of view the **BaseClass** just happens to have methods by the same name.

When you **explicitly** declare that the **ChildClass** also implements the interface, then its methods will be the best choice.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm interested in the behaviour and in this case I can't override the method. And in the instantiation of the ChildClass it's cast to the interface, not the base class. So why is it that it's the base class's method that's being choosen by the compiler?

Comment: Because the compiler's best choice is the BaseClass which explicitly declares the the method belongs to the interface. By the compiler's point of view the childclass just happens to have a method of the same name.

Comment: I've added some more about this to the answer

Comment: But i.GetType().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IBaseInterface)) returns true even when the ChildClass doesn't explicitly specify the IBaseInterface. Shouldn't it work without specifying the interface on the child class?

Comment: It does implement the interface. But the method declared in the child isn't linked to the interface. It inherits the interface from the base class. The interface's methods are linked to the father's methods because it explicitly declares to implement the interface.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the MethodToHide as virtual in your BaseClass. Then your ChildClass can override it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(v=vs.80).aspx for more details.

I believe this is the relevant part of the spec:

> **10.6.3 Virtual Methods** In a virtual method invocation, the run-time type
>   of the instance for which that
>   invocation takes place determines the
>   actual method implementation to
>   invoke. In a non-virtual method
>   invocation, the compile-time type of
>   the instance is the determining
>   factor.

So when you cast your original object to IBaseInterface. It determines that the type is BaseClass since that's the one that implements it and calls its method. In the second example it resolves it to ChildClass and calls its method.

Comment: I believe the OP is *explicity* asking about hiding, not overriding.

Comment: I can't do that as the BaseClass is a part of a third-party closed source library. And I know I could do that, I'm asking about the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Because the main-class implements the interface. The child-class just defines a new method, which has nothing to do with the interface. In fact the child class hides the method - that's what 'new' does.